# Turing machine for adding numbers

Tags: algorithms, turing-machines, arithmetic

I'm having trouble in a certain problem.

I have to write a TM that gets as an input strings $\#x\#y$ such that 
$x,y \in \{0,1\}^*$, and writes to the tape the output $z\#x\#y$ where $z = x+y$, all in binary base 2.

The addition, and knowing where to place it is rather hard. Any tips on getting started?

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?  What approaches have you considered?  Is there any simplified version of this that you *are* able to solve?  Just solving your exercise for you is probably of limited value.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pseudo-algorithm for a possible solution. I assume you know how to implement any of the sub-tasks (as they are very common and usually given as basic examples)

1. Add a $\$$ to the right of the input.
2. Duplicate the content of the tape $\$x\#y \to \$x\#y\$x\#y$
3. Add a 0 at the very start $\to 0\$x\#y\$x\#y$
4. Loop until the first $x$ is all-zero string:
   4.1 Subtract 1 from the first $x$, and add 1 to the first field, moving the input if necessary.
   4.2 remove the all-zero field that is now where $x$ was, and repeat step 4 with $y$.
   [Note: a better algorithm will skip 4.1/4.2 for $x$, and immediately start with subtracting from $y$, where the counter $z$ starts from $x$ rather than 0, but this is equivalent.]
5. Clean the $\$$ and $\#$ as necessary, move the head to the first blank, and halt.

So the only non-trivial step is how to add 1 or subtract 1 from a given number $x$ given in a binary base 2 form. I assume you know how to perform [binary arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Binary_arithmetic): for instance, for binary addition you add 1 to the LSB; if it was 0 you are done; if it was 1 you move on to the bit next to it ("carry") until you find a 0 or until you have passed the MSB (then you assume the digit after the MSB should be 0, move the input to accommodate that zero and add 1 to it).
It is a bit of a hassle to convert the algorithm into the form of a TM, but this is basically what you are requested to do. It is possible, since TM can compute any (well-defined) algorithm that a CPU-computer can do. I'll leave you to filling up the details.